# Why doesn't the bash "complete" command work inside ~/.bash_profile?

Tags: macos, bash

**Background context:** I want the ssh command on the OS X terminal to tab-complete hostnames I use frequently. On Ubuntu, ssh seems smart enough to be able to tab-complete any hostname I have in my ~/.ssh/config file. But OS X does not seem to have this behavior, so I'm trying to manually force tab-completion for some hosts I use very frequently.

If I open up a terminal and run this:

`$ complete -W foo.com ssh`

Then typing `ssh f<tab>` will complete into `ssh foo.com`

**Question: when I put such a command in my ~/.bash_profile, it no longer works. Why?**

I'm sure the ~/.bash_profile is being executed, as I have other things in there (prompt configs, etc) which are taking effect in my terminal session.

Shouldn't putting things in my ~/.bash_profile be the equivalent of automatically executing those commands in the terminal on session startup? It's as if the `complete` command runs inside a context that's lost, while other things persist (such as my PS1 prompt setting.)

Thanks for any insight here, bash experts!

**Update**

Using complete to list my configuration showed me my mistake. I'm using multiple statements, ie:

`complete -W foo.com ssh; complete -W bar.com ssh`

And only the last one takes effect (each one replaces the one before it). So, I need to put them all in one command, ie:

`complete -W 'foo bar' ssh`

So this question is not about ~/.bash_profile, it's about understanding the right way to use "complete"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Unable to Reproduce (typo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you try:

```
complete | grep ssh
```

does an entry show up?

I would recommend installing the [bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) package.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Using complete to list my configuration showed me my mistake. I updated my question and closed this out. Thanks!